# How to calculate energy of 2D free electron gas at $T = 0$?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

How to calculate energy of 2D free electron gas at $T = 0$?

I am struggling how to do this.
Know I should integrate density state over $2\pi kdk$, but not sure what should I get finally and always get lost somewhere inbetweenn...